# How can I remove hover color/circle thing on my archive posts on home page

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to figure out custom css for my home page posts on WordPress using the Sahifa theme.
How can I remove the black hover and the circle in the middle that comes with it?
No matter what I try I can't see to get rid of it.
Any help is appreciated.
http://theshellhammersspeedway.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think, it will solve your problem.

```
.archive-box .post-thumbnail a:hover img
{
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.archive-box .post-thumbnail a
{
    background: transparent;
}
.archive-box .overlay-icon
{
    display: none;
}
```